# Get all the possible combinations of one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, combinations, permutation

Let's say I have a column like this:

```
col
---
A
B
C
```

And I need all possible row combinations like the ones below:

```
result
---
A
B
C
A,B
A,C
B,C
A,B,C
```

What's the best solution to get the result?

Most of the answers that I find are suggesting joins for each row but I need something to cover variant number of rows

Comment: You probably need a recursive cte.

Comment: Why  B and  C are missing?

Comment: @Serg my bad, I fixed it

Comment: Are the original rows unique?

Comment: @Charlieface Yes they are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use recursive cte to get the desired results and as @Serg suggested, I think 'B' and 'C' should also be the part of the final result.

```
create table test(col varchar(10))
insert into test
select 'A'
union select 'B'
union select 'C'

;WITH cte (grp, col) 
AS 
(
  SELECT CAST(t.COL AS VARCHAR(100)), t.COL
  FROM TEST t
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT CAST(c.grp + ',' + t.col AS VARCHAR(100)), t.COL
  FROM TEST t
  INNER JOIN cte c
    ON c.col < t.COL
)
SELECT grp FROM cte;
```

Please see the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fd2e1d1006a927c3207b39b491e70c5f)**.